# Need to proof by induction (calculus1 n and n+1)

Tags: calculus, induction

[what needs to be proven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJEts.png)
I need to prove that for every natural n that happens and the prove needs to be by induction,
I wont prove for n=1 because its obvious,so lets move to n and n+1
$$ \frac{(2n!)}{(n!)^2} ≥ \frac{(4^n)}{(2n+1)} $$

the assumption for n+1
$$ \frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!^2} ≥ \frac{(4^{n+1})}{2n+3} $$
now I dont now how to progress,I tried this for n+1
$$ \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n!)}{(n+1)!^2} ≥ \frac{(4^{n}4^1)}{(2n+1)+2)} $$
and had a suggestion to use
$ 2n! = (n!) \prod _{n=n}^{2n}\:n\cdot )! $
but cant see how it helps,ty.

Comment: Your "suggestion" currently does not make sense. However, I think, when written properly, it could help you eliminate one of the $(n+1)!$ from the denominator.

Comment: Can you edit your "suggestion"?

Comment: It seems you mean $(2n)!=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{2n} i$ Also note that     $ 2n!\color{red}{\neq} (2n)!$

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as proving $(2n+1)(2n)!\ge4^nn!^2$, which is equivalent to $(2n+1)!\ge4^nn!^2$.

For the induction hypothesis $4^{n+1}(n+1)!^2=4·4^n(n+1)^2n!^2\le4(n+1)^2(2n+1)!$

Now $4(n+1)^2=4(n^2+2n+1)=4n^2+8n+4\le4n^2+10n+6=(2n+3)(2n+2)$, so we get $4^{n+1}(n+1)!^2\le(2n+3)(2n+2)(2n+1)!=(2n+3)!$, and rearranging again we get the result.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{(2n+2)!}{((n+1)!)^2}=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!}{(n+1)(n+1)(n!)^2}=\frac{2(2n+1)(2n)!}{(n+1)(n!)^2}\geq\frac{4^{n+1}}{2n+3}$$

Assuming that $\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\geq\dfrac{4^{n}}{2n+1}$

Let's show

$$\frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1}\frac{4^n}{2n+1}>\frac{4^{n+1}}{2n+3}$$

$$\frac{2}{n+1}>\frac{4}{2n+3}$$

$$4n+6>4n+4$$

Comment: really good answer,i understand everything you did until the point "Let`s show",how the transition to the first step in bottom made? thank you

Comment: @anton5450  :  Replacing $\frac{4^n}{2n+1}$ to LHS it will be  smaller but it is still bigger then RHS

Comment: lol i got it i think,because of what we assuming we just switched it with smaller part and its still true,im correct? if so,after that transition how you go to next step? thank you

Comment: @anton5450 : just simplify and multiply both sides by $(n+1)(2n+3)$

Comment: god bless i understood it from zero,but what 4n+6>4n+4 gives me?(sorry for stupid question) i know its true but whats the logic? thanks again

Comment: @anton5450 : finally $6>4$, it shows the assumption is true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115314/discussion-between-lion-heart-and-anton5450).

Answer (score 0):

$${2n+2\choose n+1}=\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}\cdot\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(n+1)(n+1)}\ge\frac{4^n}{2n+1}\cdot\frac{2(2n+1)}{n+1}=\frac{4^{n+1}}{2n+2}>\frac{4^{n+1}}{2n+3}$$
is it fine guys? its not mine answer but i understand it

Comment: @ anton5450: It seems fine